# Can associated constants be used to initialize the length of fixed size arrays?

Tags: rust

In C++, you have the ability to pass integrals inside templates

```cpp
std::array<int, 3> arr; //fixed size array of 3
```

I know that Rust has built in support for this, but what if I wanted to create something like linear algebra vector library?

```
struct Vec<T, size: usize> {
    data: [T; size],
}

type Vec3f = Vec<f32, 3>;
type Vec4f = Vec<f32, 4>;
```

This is currently what I do in D. I have heard that Rust now has [Associated Constants](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/associated-constants.html).

I haven't used Rust in a long time but this doesn't seem to address this problem at all or have I missed something?

As far as I can see, associated constants are only available in traits and that would mean I would still have to create `N` vector types by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, associated constants don't help *and aren't intended to*. Associated anything are *outputs* while use cases such as the one in the question want *inputs*. One could in principle construct something out of type parameters and a trait with associated constants (at least, as soon as you can use associated constants of type parameters — sadly that doesn't work yet). But that has terrible ergonomics, not much better than existing hacks like [typenum](https://crates.io/crates/typenum).

Integer type parameters are highly desired since, as you noticed, they enable numerous things that aren't really feasible in current Rust. People [talk about this and plan for it](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-integer-templating/2974) but it's not there yet.

Comment: I would note that the usefulness of non-type generic parameters (among which integers) hinges on the ability to do computations on those values at compile-time; if only `A -1`, ... I suspect that compile-time function evaluation (maybe limited to start with) is therefore necessary to get them.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Even without any computations it would already be very useful to integers around at compile time, e.g., to uniformly implement common traits for fixed-sized arrays or to reduce duplication when creating structures which are wrappers around fixed-sized arrays (such as fixed-size vectors and matrices). But I agree that computations would be even greater.

Comment: for fixed size vectors/matrices, I use the work around `SmallVec<[T; N]>`, by passing the array type directly it works (just not very elegant). I do wish a compiler trait was implemented on arrays to extract the `T` and `N` (I implement it myself with macros)... as for implementing integer parameters right now, I think that it may be premature, it's quite desirable to try and ensure that the design will be compatible with future usecases and therefore it might be better to wait until we have more experience with `const fn`.

Answer (score 2):

Integer type parameters are not supported as of now, however there's an RFC for that IIRC, and a long-standing discussion.

You could use [`typenum`](https://github.com/paholg/typenum) crate in the meanwhile.